# Service worker not generated when building vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have installed `"@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.5.12",` in my package.json, I have also added workbox configuration in my `vue.config.js`. The problem is, when I'm building the project with `npm run build:prd` which has my script: `vue-cli-service build --mode prod.example`, there is no `service-worker.js` in my dist folder.

this is my vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    // ...other vue-cli plugin options...
    pwa: {
        // configure the workbox plugin
        workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
        workboxOptions: {
            // swSrc is required in InjectManifest mode.
            swSrc: 'src/service-worker.js',
            // ...other Workbox options...
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to move the pwa plugin configuration inside package.json, but it doesn't work as well. I just can't find my `service-worker.js` in my dist folder.

The current workaround is I place my `service-worker.js` inside my `pubic` folder. The problem with this approach is that the service worker will not be updated at all every time there is a new release. Currently the purpose is to notify the client if the new version is available, but I can't trigger the `update` event because the `service-worker.js` is static

Comment: may be a bug in vue3, but that looks similar to what I have in vue2 - thing is, in the past, I've used the default *GenerateSW* plugin mode - and update is triggered - I simply added a `document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('swUpdated', { detail: registration }));` in the `updated` callback in `registerServiceWorker.js` and some associated code in `App.vue` to show there's an update

Comment: I have done that, but the problem is if I use `GenerateSW` the registration failed, because `registerServiceWorker` can't find my `service-worker.js`

Comment: as I said, must be a vue3 bug then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, `@vue/cli-plugin-pwa` will only generate `service-worker` if `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'`. meanwhile in my project, when i run `npm run build` the `NODE_ENV` is not automatically set to `production` but it's still `development` I don't know what is causing this behavior, but the problem is solved if i add `NODE_ENV=production` in all of my `.env`. With this, `precache-manifest....js` will be generated on every build.